# Adobe Encoder fps and duration doesn't match

Tags: after-effects, encoding, framerate, adobe-media-encoder

I have After Effects project file 25 fps, 29 seconds duration long. After exporting i get 725 png files - looks normal so far. But then i merge it to mp4 using Adobe Encoder, I get total 24 seconds duration instead of 29.

```
Math:
725 frames,  25 fps  -  29 s
725 frames,  30 fps  -  24 s
```

The strange thing in mp4 file properties - 25 fps and 24s duration which doesn't make sense, it doesn't match math. Please any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

### [image]

EDIT:

I find out in AE Preferences > Import image sequence footage fps by default was set to 30. After changing it to 25 imported image sequence looks good.

[image]
Unfortunately I couldn't find it in Adobe Encoder preferences - there is no such settings, and by default it loads 30fps sequence.

Comment: Something somewhere in your chain is assuming 30fps, as your math clearly shows. Examine everything, especially the timeline specs.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately I couldn't find it in Adobe Encoder preferences - there is no such settings, and by default it loads 30fps sequence.

You can change the default in Media Encoder by going to the Preferences/Media and then change "Indeterminate Media Timebase"